# Infinite Loop waiting a process on C

Tags: c, unix, posix

I'm trying to make a main process wait for the completion of the process instructed by waitpid, but right on the call to waitpid, an infinite loop occurs.

It seems that the process referenced by waitpid never ends.

This process is always an execlp to unix command, as wc, rev, cat ...

If I comment the code concerning waitpid, unix command ends perfectly.

Deputy code for the call to the mandate and the wait:

```
int pid;
int estado_proceso;


for(pid=0;pid<numFiltros;pid++)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"A esperar a %d\n", pids[pid]);

    if (waitpid(pids[pid],&estado_proceso,0) >= 0)
        imprimir_estado(filtros[pid], estado_proceso);

    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error al esperar proceso %d\n",pid);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

---

```
fprintf(stderr,"A ejecutar comando \n");
            execlp(filtro,filtro, NULL);
            fprintf(stderr,"Error al ejecutar el mandato '%s'\n",filtro);
            exit(1);
```

Edit:
Fork and Pid obtain code:

```
switch(pid = fork())
    {
    /* Error en el Fork */
    case -1:
        fprintf (stderr,"Error al crear proceso %d\n", pid);
        exit(1);
```

---

```
/* Father Process*/
    default:
    pids[i-1] = pid;
```

---

On Main:

pids = (pid_t*) malloc (sizeof(pid_t)*numFiltros);

Where "numFiltros" is the number of unix commands like wc, cat, rev...

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you obtain the child process PID? Can you show us the fork? _Also, having variables and functions name in English helps a lot (now I have to think about what they mean which slows me down)_

Comment: I have posted the code you said. Yeah, I will name variables and functions in english next time . Sorry :/

Comment: Does it work when you only run 1 command (child process)? Can you print the child process PID upon its creation and before the `waitpid` call to make sure you have it right?

Comment: If i run 1 command, I have an infinite Loop when waitpid waits for 5564 process. Looking this number i think the PID is valid. If y try to run with 2 or more commands, the result is the same, the waitpid blocks the main process forever. But, If i Comment the waitpid code, all works perfectly.

Comment: The main process connects his output to the stdin of first child. The first child connects his output to the stdin of his child and sucessively (with pipes).

Comment: And does the main process close the pipe before waiting for the children processes? They might not quit otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `wait` instead of explicit `waitpid`, that is, try replacing your waiting code with

```c
int pid;
int estado_proceso;

while((pid = wait(&estado_proceso)) >= 0) {
    if(pid > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Process with PID %d terminated.\n", pid);
        imprimir_estado(pid, estado_proceso);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Honestly I don´t know why. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Try to print the PID values stored in your array and PID values returned by the `wait` call. If their order differs, then you know why it wouldn't work before.